# SubDomain Authentication Mechanism & Session Maintainance

Tags: session, authentication, jwt, access-token, session-state

**SCENARIO**

There are 3 Domains (2 of which is sub Domain)

- https://site1.thatsme.org  - Main web site (.NET)
- https://site2.thatsme.org  - Sub Domain web site (NODE)
- https://api.thatsnotme.org - REST Api Server (NODE)

---

*Site1*

- Independent site

*Site2*

- Completely Depends on api for all operation

*api*

- Depend on site1 only for authentication

---

**ISSUE**

Site1 only has a login Page

A user Logs in to Site1 and has to be able to go to site2 as logged in user Where site2 uses the REST api server for all its operation including the authentication (Has to be Provided by site1).

What will be the Best Approach For this ?

---

Answer (score 2):

session vs token alternatives :

- **Session cookie**: site 1 authenticates user and creates a server session identified with a unique sessionId cookie. It is discarded because cookies can not be shared across domains easily and it also implies sharing server session
- **Authentication token**: site 1 generates a random token after a successful user authentication, and redirects to site 2. Site 2 stores the token and uses it to call API. The token can be stored in client side if you are building a SPA(Single Page Application) or server side using a session for each user if your application is form-based.

About the token strategy, you can use:

- **opaque tokens**: A random string assigned to user and stored in site 1. Both site 2 and API should query site 1 when they receive a token to verify if it is active and to whom it corresponds
- **Json Web Tokens (JWT)**: Token is self-contained, includes user identity and some othed claims of interests such us expiration time or audience. The token is signed with the secret key of site 1, so it is protected against alteration. Site 2 and API can verify JWT without querying online to site1, and server storage it is not needed. In this case it is needed an assymetric key pair private-public (RSA). The token is signed with private key and verified with the public

**Summarizing**: JWT simplifies your development, reduces server-to-server linkage and requires fewer resources

Comment: Would it be better if jwt is sliced from site1
-----
**Site1** - puts unique _UserId_  (encrypted with public key of api) in cookie under thatsme.org .............

**Site2** - has access to that cookie & transfers to api server if no session exist...........

**api** - decrypts  the userid with its private key and and creates jwt which is stored in site2 session ...........

**Site2** - later uses jwt for all api calls to api server

Comment: In this solution the encryption does not add security. Anyone who steals an ID, encrypted or unencrypted, could impersonate the user at all times. And you would have to change the keys of the whole system. It is convenient for site1 to generate the JWT